# Applescript: move all files with a certain extension to the trash

Tags: applescript

This is very straightforward; it moves `myfile.WMA` to the trash:

```
tell application "Finder"
    move POSIX file "/Volumes/DS_30/myfolder/myfile.WMA" to trash
end tell
```

But how would I move all files in `myfolder` with a extension of `.WMA` to the trash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example *volume* and *folder* name:

```
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    move (every item of ¬
        container (alias "DS_30:myfolder") of ¬
        application "Finder" whose name extension = "WMA") to trash
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I don't need the POSIX path after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppleScript's [filter reference form](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-BAJJHEFE) - for example:

```
set myFolder to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder"
   try
      set theItems to files of myFolder whose name extension is "wma"
   on error errmess -- shell script
      log errmess
      set theItems to paragraphs of (do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of POSIX path of myFolder & " -depth 1 -iname '*.wma' -print")
      repeat with anItem in theItems
         set contents of anItem to anItem as POSIX file as alias
      end repeat
   end try
   move theItems to the trash
end tell
```

Note that the filter reference works for application objects, not regular AppleScript objects such as lists and records.

**Edit**

Added a statement to perform a `find` shell script in the event of an error.

Comment: Thanks! That should work, But when I use `set myFolder to "Volumes:DS_30:DS_30/myfolder:"` I get `Can’t get every file of \"Volumes:DS_30:DS_30/myfolder:\"." number -1728 from every file of "Volumes:DS_30:DS_30/myfolder:"`

Comment: I think the Finder uses Spotlight for the search - is the external volume indexed?

Comment: I don't think so; it's MS-DOS formatted memory chip on a digital recorder.

Comment: I didn't notice the slash in your file path - try `"Volumes:DS_30:DS_30:myfolder:"`

Comment: Arg, my typo; still the same -1728 error, though, using `"Volumes:DS_30:myfolder:"`

Comment: I added a shell script to try to find the items in the event of an error.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch The error was due to your setting `myFolder` to a string value rather than a `folder` or an `alias` object. Your file path is also wrong. You most likely want `set myFolder to folder "DS_30:myfolder:"`. So, overall, a working solution would simply be `tell application "Finder" to delete (every file in folder "DS_30:myfolder:" whose name extension = "wma")`. Or, with a posix path: `tell application "Finder" to delete (every file in folder POSIX file "/Volumes/DS_30/myfolder" whose name extension = "wma")`.

Comment: @red_menace Thanks! Looks like user3439894 has the cleaner answer.